# How can I make list changes animations while using custom way of saving data RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, list, android-recyclerview, android-animation

I'm making a memo app that uses a RecyclerView to show an `ArrayList<Note>` of data where `Note` is a data class for each item, and I save and retrieve them using another class called NotesController (using Gson). In order to update the list, what I do now is reassign a new value to the NotesAdapter (the RecyclerView Adapter) I've set to my list. Here's my code:

**NotesController:**

```java
public class NotesController {

    private ArrayList<Note> notesList;
    private String notesPath;

    private Gson gson = new Gson();
    private Type type = new TypeToken<ArrayList<Note>>() {
    }.getType();

    public NotesController(String notesPath) {
        this.notesPath = notesPath;
        if (FileUtil.isExistFile(notesPath)) {
            getNotesList();
        } else {
            createNewList();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Creates a new list if it doesn't exist. Internal class use only.
     */
    private void createNewList() {
        notesList = new ArrayList<>();
        saveLatestData();
    }

    /**
     * Reads the saved notes.json file and retrieves the ArrayList of items of class {@link Note}.
     * @return An ArrayList<<h>Note</h>> containing all notes saved in file <b>notes.json</b>
     */
    public ArrayList<Note> getNotesList() {
        String json = FileUtil.readFile(notesPath);
        notesList = gson.fromJson(json, type);
        return notesList;
    }

    /**
     * Saves latest changes to the list {@linkplain NotesController#notesList} to notes.json file. Internal class use only.
     */
    private void saveLatestData() {
        String json = gson.toJson(notesList, type);
        FileUtil.writeFile(notesPath, json);
    }

    /**
     * Adds an item of type {@link Note} to the list and saves data by calling {@link NotesController#saveLatestData()}.
     * @param note The {@link Note} instance to get added.
     */
    public void add(Note note) {
        notesList.add(0, note);
        saveLatestData();
    }

    /**
     * Replaces an existing item with a new one of type {@link Note} in the list {@link NotesController#notesList} and saves data by calling {@link NotesController#saveLatestData()}.
     * @param position The position of the item to get replaced.
     * @param note The {@link Note} instance to replace the old item.
     * @throws ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException When position is out of {@link NotesController#notesList} range.
     */
    public void set(int position, Note note) {
        notesList.set(position, note);
        saveLatestData();
    }

    /**
     * Gets the {@link Note} item from the specified position.
     * @param position The position of the item to return.
     * @return The item at the position specified.
     * @throws ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException When position is out of {@link NotesController#notesList} range.
     */
    public Note get(int position) {
        return notesList.get(position);
    }

    /**
     * Removes the {@link Note} item in the specified position from the list.
     * @param position The position of the item to remove.
     * @throws ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException When position is out of {@link NotesController#notesList} range.
     */
    public void remove(int position) {
        notesList.remove(position);
        saveLatestData();
    }

    /**
     * Indexes the notes list for the given text and returns items that contain the query either in the title or the content.
     * @param query The text query to search for (low cased).
     * @return The notes whose title or content contains the query (all trimmed and low cased).
     */
    public ArrayList<Note> search(String query) {
        ArrayList<Note> results = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Note note: getNotesList()) {
            if (note.getTitle().trim().toLowerCase().contains(query.trim().toLowerCase()) || note.getContent().trim().toLowerCase().contains(query.trim().toLowerCase())) {
                results.add(note);
            }
        }
        return results;
    }

    /**
     * Simple method to convert many int parameters to an int[] array.
     * @param categories The varargs int[] array.
     * @return int[] array from parameters.
     */
    public int[] categories(int... categories) {
        return categories;
    }
}
```

**MainActivity:** *(just the relevant codes)*

```java
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private NotesAdapter notesAdapter;
    public static NotesController notesController;
    private RecyclerView notesRecyclerView;
    private String notesDir;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Fabric.with(this, new Answers(), new Crashlytics());
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ...

        notesDir = ContextCompat.getDataDir(this).getPath() + "/files/notes.json";
        notesController = new NotesController(notesDir);

        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        notesRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        updateRecyclerView();

        notesAdapter.setOnItemActionListener(new NotesAdapter.ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(final int position, View v) {
                ...
            }

            @Override
            public void onItemLongClick(final int position, View v) {
                AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this).setTitle("Delete?").setMessage("Just for testing.");
                dialog.setPositiveButton("DELETE", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                        notesController.remove(position);
                        updateRecyclerView();
                    }
                });
                dialog.show();
            }
        });

        ...
    }

    ...

    private void updateRecyclerView() {
        notesAdapter = new NotesAdapter(notesController.getNotesList(), getApplicationContext());
        notesRecyclerView.setAdapter(notesAdapter);
        notesAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

}
```

Now looking at `updateRecyclerView()` method you see that I reassign the Adapter once again with the new data from the NotesController then notify the list that the data changed.

But I need somehow, without eliminating the controller, to make list make deletion animation when I delete (e.g. by long click) or add something (just the default one). And for that, Android RecyclerView Adapter class provides us with `notifyItemInserted(int)` and `notifyItemRemoved(int)` but they didn't work in my case (even with removing notifyDataSetChanged() which interrupts these animations).

Please don't suggest me to eliminate the NotesController as it helps accessing notes from different parts of the app easily, and I just need a way for those two insertion and deletion notifying methods to work without problems (any other solution is welcome btw).

Note: Here's my adapter type: `public class NotesAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<NotesAdapter.NoteViewHolder>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't create new instance of adapter whenever you want to update items in recyclerview. You should create one instance of adapter and assign it to recyclerview, if you want to add or remove items in recyclerview, you just need to replace data in adapter. I would recommend `ListAdapter` because it has function `submitList(list)` which can be easily use to update data.

Also if you want to achieve animations you can use [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/leanback/widget/DiffCallback)

Comment: Thanks bro I'll check that out!

Comment: `public class NotesAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<NotesAdapter.NoteViewHolder>` does not have any function called `submitList(list);`. Is there any alternative? Or should I create such a thing?

Comment: Read this article for reference. It uses `ListAdapter` that I mentioned. https://hmkcode.com/android/android-recyclerview-listadapter/

Comment: Thank you so much for you assistance but I fixed the problem by making my own submitData() function into the adapter and animations automatically worked (with `notifyItemRemoved/Added()` ) !!

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem by using -as suggested by Milan Kundacina- the function `submitList(list)` instead of reassigning the adapter. But as this function comes only with ListAdapter while I'm using Adapter only, I've created my own one as follows (suuuuuper simple):

```java
public class NotesAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<NotesAdapter.NoteViewHolder> {

    private ArrayList<Note> notesList;

    ...

    NotesAdapter(ArrayList<Note> notesList) {
        super();
        this.notesList = notesList;
    }

    public void submitList(ArrayList<Note> list) {
        this.notesList = list;
    }

    ...

}
```

And used this way to update the list:

```java
// inside MainActivity:

private void notifyListAdd(int position) {
    notesAdapter.submitList(notesController.getNotesList());
    notesAdapter.notifyItemInserted(position);
}

private void notifyListRemove(int position) {
    notesAdapter.submitList(notesController.getNotesList());
    notesAdapter.notifyItemRemoved(position);
}
```